# Django on Nginx connection refused

Tags: python, django, nginx

I want to run my django app on nginx webserver + gunicorn.
I have setup most of the stuff already following tutorials and got to the point where I need to setup Nginx.
I have my app in:

```
/home/ec2-user/davidbien
```

That's also where my virtualenv is installed. 
Inside davidbien folder I have the below script guni.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="test"                                  
DJANGODIR=/home/ec2-user/davidbien             
SOCKFILE=/home/ec2-user/virtual/run/gunicorn.sock 
USER=ec2-user                                        
GROUP=ec2-user                                     
NUM_WORKERS=3                                      
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=davidbien.settings            
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=davidbien.wsgi                    

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../virtual/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# (do not use --daemon)
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
--name $NAME \
--workers $NUM_WORKERS \
--user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
--bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
--log-level=debug \
--log-file=-
```

This seems to be running fine as I don't get anything when running it. I can also run the app using

```
gunicorn davidbien.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

This works fine.

Now, I get to nginx setup.
I installed it and created two folders - sites-available and sites-enabled inside /etc/nginx/.
I then created a file test.conf inside sites-available and inserted the below code inside:

```
upstream app_server_djangoapp {
server 35.177.26.219:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name 35.177.26.219;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/guni-access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/guni-error.log info;

keepalive_timeout 5;

# path for static files
root /home/ec2-user/davidbien/davidbien/static;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://app_server_djangoapp;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

I also edited nginx.conf file like below:

```
http {
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /sites-enabled/*.*;

 # Load configuration files for the default server block.
 include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
 }
```

I restart nginx and I get this error:

This site can’t be reached
35.177.26.219 refused to connect.

After checking logs I found this:

```
2017/11/11 17:21:43 [error] 3524#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refuseed) while connecting to upstream, client: 2.96.149.96, server: 35.177.26.219, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://35.177.26.219:8000/favicon.ico", host: "35.177.26.219", referrer: "http://35.177.26.219/"
```

Apologies for a lengthy explanation.
Now the question is, what is wrong?
Thanks.

EDIt: As per Marco's comment here's the log from gunicorn:

```
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: No application module specified.
```

EDIT2: Edited gunicorn script.

Comment: Have you set your **ALLOWED_HOSTS** in `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it wouldn't run in gunicorn nor even django's environment.

Comment: Have you tyried `--log-level debug` when starting gunicorn to collect some more information?

Comment: I changed one thing in gunicorn script. I noticed it's saying `exec gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS --bind=$ADDRESS \` so I changed that to gunicorn, not gunicorn_django. I updated my original post with the current logs from gunicorn.

Comment: You don't seem to be pointing the exec command to davidbien.wsgi

Comment: I've edited that script in my original post now. I still can't get it to work.

Comment: A quick question. When I run guni.sh script and gunicorn starts working should I be able to access any content? When I run gunicorn script I can see it starting but I cannot access the webpage.